# What is white hairy like substance growing on the bottom of an otherwise healthy hibiscus?

Tags: leaves, hibiscus

The leaves are green, but a hairy-like substance is hanging about 2 inches on the underside of the hibiscus. Currently, it is affecting a small cluster of leaves (about 12 leaves). Otherwise the plant is healthy and blooming. The affected area is in shade and down low on the plant. Any ideas? [image]

Comment: Never seen anything like that before - have you poked around inside the white fibres or looked with a magnifying glass to see if there is an inhabitant or two, such as small caterpillars? Anything odd under  the leaves, where the fibres are coming from?

Comment: We cut off those branches, and white flies are flying around the area. In researching, we suspect they're called giant white flies. We're hosing down the area as recommended. Weirdest thing we've ever seen

Comment: Fascinating, never heard of giant whitefly, never mind seen such a thing as these dangly filaments, but I looked it up and I think you're right - image  here is very similar https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2010/06/14/giant-whitefly/. Thanks for  letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

That is from Giant white Flys! look on the bottom of the leaf and you will see thousands of eggs and many of the live flys, ewwww pretty gross! spray with Neem oil every 7 to 14 days until clear